# Dynamic Query Builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a custom MySQL database query `UI`. Inside this UI I have a Query Builder interface that I would like to dynamically append query properties based on the user selections in order to create a dynamic query. Please see the below picture for a visual description

[image: Query Builder UI]

From the picture above I would like to append `CHARACTER_SET` after the FROM and append as asterisk when `ALL` is selected from the table and so forth with the key being the positions where I place the generated variables.

How can I achieve this with JQuery?

My JavaScript

> Selecting a Table

```
$(document).on("change", ".tbl_list", function () {
    var tbls = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
        tbls.push($(this).val());
    });
    var tbl = tbls.join('|');
    var db = window.sessionStorage.getItem("db");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax2.php",
        data: {
            tbl: tbl,
            db: db
        },
        success: function (html) {
            console.log(html);
            $("#tblField").html(html).show();
        }
    });
});
```

> Selecting All option

```
  $(document).on("click", ".tblall", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Iterate each checkbox
            $('.tblst').each(function () {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        } else {
            $('.tblst').each(function () {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

> As requested HTML for my DIVs

*Table Selector*

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $tbl_list ) ) {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tbl[]" class="tbl_list"
    value="<?php echo   $row [0];   ?>" />
 <?php echo $row [0]; ?> 
<br>
```

*Query Builder*

```
<div id="qryDisplay">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Query Builder</legend>
                <div id="qryView">
                    <p>SELECT   FROM</p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

> What I have tried so far

Using `.append` I can add data to the end of the paragraph so this would be ideal for my Table name. However its a function and i'm not sure how I would implement the code below into my select table function.

```
$("#qryView > p").append("  " tblName);
```

Comment: This is not so hard, but we need the relevant HTML code as well (Table Selector and Query Display(currently `SELECT FROM`))

Comment: Edited the OP please have a look.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of it... can you actually select more than one table? And if yes, what's the query supposed to look like?

Comment: Yes you can select multiple tables. I would be using  `FROM table1, table2`. Would probably need to use UNION but I just want it to work for one table first and then improve it

Comment: `Select * FROM table1, table2` gives just a rubbish useless result, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, not considering the logic behind the selection of multiple tables my approach would be to store selections in hidden input fields and at the end construct from the hidden fields the query.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="hiddenTables" id="hiddenTables" />
```

fill field according to selections in your function from above:

```
$("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
    tbls.push($(this).val());
    if($('#hiddenTables').val() == ""){ 
       $('#hiddenTables').val($(this).val()); 
    }else{
       $('#hiddenTables').val($('#hiddenTables').val()+','+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

At the end create your query:

```
// hidden field for field selection, same as above.
var fieldselection = '*';
if($('#hiddenFieldselection').val() != ""){
    fieldselection = $('#hiddenFieldselection').val();
}

$("#qryView > p").html("SELECT " + fieldselection + " FROM " + $('#hiddenTables').val());
```

This needs to be adjusted the way you need it of course and I haven't tested any of this... So that's up to you :-)

Comment: Unrecoverable Syntax Error on  `if($('#hiddenTables')val() == ""){` ??

Comment: `if($('#hiddenTables').val() == "")` missing dot

Comment: okay I fixed a few more, hopefully all errors, the 3rd `=` in the if statement is not necessary, I only use `===` to check for `true` or `false`

Comment: `var fieldselection = '*';
if($('#hiddenFieldselection').val() != "")` fieldselection value is already empty as per your suggestion. If you run that code the way you wrote, it will print and `[object Object]` error instead of an asterisk. You say you didn't run the code yourself but are not willing to accept working edits but you want upvote?????

Comment: not enough reputation to accept edits :-) and i added the `.val()` to that if statement

Comment: `.val()` isn't the problem the value is already empty.... you need to use `=` instead of `!=` https://jsfiddle.net/fjfcz98v/  .....anyway I upvoted just fix the errors please for future reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74099/discussion-between-noobatnerd-and-edwin-krause).